# Hibernate connection with MySql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have an issue with "spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect" it can't be recognized by eclipse, and I don't know why. Below is my Pom.xml and application.properties any suggestion would be great. Is there any other solution how can I connect hibernate with MySql? Thank you

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <tiles.version>3.0.5</tiles.version>
</properties>

<groupId>com.caveofprogramming</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-tutorial</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<packaging>war</packaging>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

```
server.port=9099
debug=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springboottutorial
spring.datasource.username=springboot
spring.datasource.password=hello
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG




    2016-11-27 21:55:24.324  INFO 8048 --- [           main] com.caveofprogramming.App                : Starting App on Norby-PC with PID 8048 (started by Norby in C:\Users\Norby\Documents\Java EE-2\springboot-master\springboot-master\spring-boot-tutorial-connecting)
2016-11-27 21:55:24.328  INFO 8048 --- [           main] com.caveofprogramming.App                : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-11-27 21:55:24.328 DEBUG 8048 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Loading source class com.caveofprogramming.App
2016-11-27 21:55:24.490 DEBUG 8048 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Loaded config file 'classpath:/application.properties'
2016-11-27 21:55:24.490 DEBUG 8048 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Skipped (empty) config file 'classpath:/application.properties' for profile default
2016-11-27 21:55:24.498  INFO 8048 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@71a794e5: startup date [Sun Nov 27 21:55:24 GMT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-11-27 21:55:24.505 DEBUG 8048 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Bean factory for org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@71a794e5: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1ed1993a: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory,app]; root of factory hierarchy
2016-11-27 21:55:28.386 DEBUG 8048 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.AutoConfigurationPackages        : @EnableAutoConfiguration was declared on a class in the package 'com.caveofprogramming'. Automatic @Repository and @Entity scanning is enabled.
2016-11-27 21:55:29.327  INFO 8048 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$785ab572] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-11-27 21:55:29.410 DEBUG 8048 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@5b6e8f77]
2016-11-27 21:55:29.410 DEBUG 8048 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Using ApplicationEventMulticaster [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@41a6d121]
2016-11-27 21:55:30.486 DEBUG 8048 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Code archive: C:\Users\Norby\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.3.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar
2016-11-27 21:55:30.486 DEBUG 8048 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Code archive: C:\Users\Norby\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.3.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar
2016-11-27 21:55:30.487 DEBUG 8048 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Document root: C:\Users\Norby\Documents\Java EE-2\springboot-master\springboot-master\spring-boot-tutorial-connecting\src\main\webapp
2016-11-27 21:55:30.596  INFO 8048 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9099 (http)
2016-11-27 21:55:30.626  INFO 8048 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-11-27 21:55:30.629  INFO 8048 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.33
2016-11-27 21:55:31.600  INFO 8048 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2016-11-27 21:55:31.609  INFO 8048 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-11-27 21:55:31.610  INFO 8048 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 7116 ms
2016-11-27 21:55:31.819 DEBUG 8048 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Added existing Servlet initializer bean 'dispatcherServletRegistration'; order=2147483647, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletConfiguration.class]
2016-11-27 21:55:32.283 DEBUG 8048 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Created Filter initializer for bean 'characterEncodingFilter'; order=-2147483648, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration.class]
2016-11-27 21:55:32.283 DEBUG 8048 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Created Filter initializer for bean 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter'; order=-10000, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]
2016-11-27 21:55:32.284 DEBUG 8048 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Created Filter initializer for bean 'httpPutFormContentFilter'; order=-9900, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]
2016-11-27 21:55:32.284 DEBUG 8048 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Created Filter initializer for bean 'requestContextFilter'; order=-105, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]
2016-11-27 21:55:32.290  INFO 8048 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-11-27 21:55:32.296  INFO 8048 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-11-27 21:55:32.297  INFO 8048 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-11-27 21:55:32.297  INFO 8048 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-11-27 21:55:32.297  INFO 8048 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-11-27 21:55:32.334 DEBUG 8048 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Initializing filter 'requestContextFilter'
2016-11-27 21:55:32.337 DEBUG 8048 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Filter 'requestContextFilter' configured successfully
2016-11-27 21:55:32.338 DEBUG 8048 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.b.c.w.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter : Initializing filter 'httpPutFormContentFilter'
2016-11-27 21:55:32.339 DEBUG 8048 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.b.c.w.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter : Filter 'httpPutFormContentFilter' configured successfully
2016-11-27 21:55:32.339 DEBUG 8048 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.w.OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter  : Initializing filter 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter'
2016-11-27 21:55:32.339 DEBUG 8048 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.w.OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter  : Filter 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' configured successfully
2016-11-27 21:55:32.340 DEBUG 8048 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.w.OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter : Initializing filter 'characterEncodingFilter'
2016-11-27 21:55:32.341 DEBUG 8048 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.w.OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter : Filter 'characterEncodingFilter' configured successfully
Sun Nov 27 21:55:32 GMT 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sun Nov 27 21:55:33 GMT 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sun Nov 27 21:55:33 GMT 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sun Nov 27 21:55:33 GMT 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sun Nov 27 21:55:33 GMT 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sun Nov 27 21:55:33 GMT 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sun Nov 27 21:55:33 GMT 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sun Nov 27 21:55:33 GMT 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sun Nov 27 21:55:33 GMT 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sun Nov 27 21:55:33 GMT 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2016-11-27 21:55:33.271  INFO 8048 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-11-27 21:55:33.294  INFO 8048 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2016-11-27 21:55:33.536  INFO 8048 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
2016-11-27 21:55:33.539  INFO 8048 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-11-27 21:55:33.542  INFO 8048 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-11-27 21:55:33.908  INFO 8048 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-11-27 21:55:34.019  INFO 8048 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2016-11-27 21:55:34.323  INFO 8048 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-11-27 21:55:34.620  INFO 8048 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator     : HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: com.caveofprogramming.model.StatusUpdate (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
2016-11-27 21:55:35.101  INFO 8048 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2016-11-27 21:55:35.101  INFO 8048 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
2016-11-27 21:55:35.103  INFO 8048 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000396: Updating schema
2016-11-27 21:55:35.141  INFO 8048 --- [           main] java.sql.DatabaseMetaData                : HHH000262: Table not found: status_update
2016-11-27 21:55:35.144  INFO 8048 --- [           main] java.sql.DatabaseMetaData                : HHH000262: Table not found: status_update
2016-11-27 21:55:35.145  INFO 8048 --- [           main] java.sql.DatabaseMetaData                : HHH000262: Table not found: status_update
2016-11-27 21:55:35.592  INFO 8048 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000232: Schema update complete
2016-11-27 21:55:35.800  INFO 8048 --- [           main] org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess      : Publishing TilesContext for context: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.SpringWildcardServletTilesApplicationContext
2016-11-27 21:55:36.212  INFO 8048 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@71a794e5: startup date [Sun Nov 27 21:55:24 GMT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-11-27 21:55:36.368  INFO 8048 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/admin]}" onto java.lang.String com.caveofprogramming.controllers.AuthController.admin()
2016-11-27 21:55:36.371  INFO 8048 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/addstatus]}" onto java.lang.String com.caveofprogramming.controllers.PageController.addStatus()
2016-11-27 21:55:36.371  INFO 8048 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto java.lang.String com.caveofprogramming.controllers.PageController.home()
2016-11-27 21:55:36.371  INFO 8048 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/about]}" onto java.lang.String com.caveofprogramming.controllers.PageController.about()
2016-11-27 21:55:36.375  INFO 8048 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-11-27 21:55:36.376  INFO 8048 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-11-27 21:55:36.446  INFO 8048 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-11-27 21:55:36.446  INFO 8048 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-11-27 21:55:36.531  INFO 8048 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-11-27 21:55:37.046  INFO 8048 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-11-27 21:55:37.058 DEBUG 8048 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@7a83ccd2]
2016-11-27 21:55:37.069 DEBUG 8048 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 






Exclusions:
```

---

```
None
Unconditional classes:
----------------------
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration
      org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration    
2016-11-27 21:55:37.427  INFO 8048 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 9099 (http)
2016-11-27 21:55:37.436  INFO 8048 --- [           main] com.caveofprogramming.App                : Started App in 14.024 seconds (JVM running for 15.077)
```

Comment: What's the exception ? Post it here

Comment: I just figured out it's working, table has been created into MySql but I'm not sure if I need this line of code "spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect". I've followed tutorial and that is the reason why I'm confused. Thanks

Comment: There is no property `spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect`... instead you should use either `spring.jpa.database-platform` or `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect`.

Comment: @M.Deinum     Thank you!